# Printing a data.frame with zero columns but still has row.names?

Tags: r

Is there a built-in function to display a data.frame with zero columns but still show row.names?

```
> df
 DataFrame with 5 rows and 0 columns

> row.names(df)
[1] "ID1"  "ID2" "ID3" "ID4" "ID5"
```

It would be useful if instead:

```
> df
DataFrame with 5 rows and 0 columns
ID1 
ID2 
ID3 
ID4 
ID5
```

I wrote a custom function to do it via `cat`, but would be nice to know if there's a built-in way of doing it.

Comment: Would not this do? `data.frame(row.names = paste0("ID", 1:5))`

Comment: This might be one of those "do you _really_ need that" questions. As you showed already, the row names are present and can be accessed if required. Do you really gain any extra information by printing a bunch of empty cells alongside them?

Comment: I suppose you could convert to tibble and show the rownames in a column: `dplyr::as_tibble(df, rownames = "rownames")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  select(-everything())

cat(print(df), cat(rownames(df), sep = "\n"))
```

Or could also be simplified to:

```
df %>%
  select(-everything()) %>%
  cat(print(.), cat(rownames(.), sep = "\n"))
```

Output

```
data frame with 0 columns and 2 rows
A
B
```

Or using base R, if you don't care about the information being displayed about the dataframe.

```
df <- df[1]
df[1] <- rep("", nrow(df))
colnames(df) <- ""
```

Output

```
A 
B
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2),
                 b = c(1, 2),
                 c = c(4, 5))

rownames(df) <- c("A", "B")
```